# virtual comport is very slow compared to terminal

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, .net-3.5, virtual-serial-port

I'm writing an application where I need to send a file (~600kB) to another unit via a virtual serialport.

When I send it using a terminal application (TeraTerm) it takes less than 10 seconds, but using my program it takes 1-2 minutes.

My code is very simple:

```
port.WriteTimeout = 30000;
port.ReadTimeout = 5000;
port.WriteBufferSize = 1024 * 1024; // Buffer size larger than file size
...
fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
byte[] filedata = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(filedata, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
...
for (int iter = 0; iter < filedata.Length; iter++) {
    port.Write(filedata, iter, 1);
}
```

Calling port.Write with the entire file length seems to always cause a write timeout for unknown reason, so I'm writing 1 byte at a time.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx): "If there are too many bytes in the output buffer and Handshake is set to XOnXOff then the SerialPort object may raise a TimeoutException while it waits for the device to be ready to accept more data."

Comment: Did you set the right [BaudRate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.baudrate(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Try writing in bigger packets. Try 16, then 32, and so on up to 1024

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I set it to port.Handshake = Handshake.None (But code is omitted in the post, didn't think it was important)

Comment: @spender It's a virtual comport, baudrate doesn't matter. It's set to 115.2k just in case

Comment: @xanatos I've tried to send it in 1024 byte packets, but it doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, here's the details in case someone else finds this it might give some hints on what's wrong.

I was reading the file wrong, somehow the application used \r\n as newlines when transferring. The file itself is a Intel .hex file which contains checksums which were calculated using \r as newlines.

Checksum errors caused the other device to ACK very slowly, thus making the transfer super slow combined with the PC application now handling checking for checksum errors.

If you have similar errors I recommend using a [software snoop](http://www.serialmon.com/) to monitor what's actually being sent